# Long strings in system Keyboard plist settings

Tags: ios, keyboard, plist, jailbreak

I try add my own characters in keyboard.
I expand key 'z' by code to "Keyboard-en.plist":

```
"Roman-Accent-z" =     {
    Keycaps = "z mylongstringtitle ..."; // ... == \U017e \U017a \U017c characters ('z' with apostrophes and dots)
    Strings = "z mylongstringvalue ...";
};
```

But keyboard not shown my string 'mylongstringtitle', only blank space ' ':
[image]

I can add only string 4 chars length on normal font and 7 chars on small font on 'button'. But I need add a long string.

Can I add 'mylongstringtitle' inside keycaps's string? May be I need set special parameters for long string? This is possible?

Comment: I think for this you need to create custom keyboard.

Comment: No, I don't need my own custom keyboard for my own app. I need find solution for system iOS keyboard with add my 'strings' inside chars.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you will be able to add long string to be displayed in `keyboard-en.plist`. I believe the limitations of 4/7chars that you discovered are hard-coded in desire to avoid disfigured popup.

Answer (score 0):

This keyboard behavior is not supported by Apple (it's not documented on http://developer.apple.com, or http://devforums.apple.com).  Use of this feature in your app, therefore, is undefined behavior, which is considered programmer error.

That said, it's a neat feature.  The limits of 4 and 7 characters for keycaps are hardcoded on iOS.  I can't find them in any of the keyboard plists.  You'd probably have to modify the keyboard binary to do what you want.  (On OS X, on the other hand, this limit does not exist.)

A few alternatives exist, which you might know about:

- You could modify [this custom keyboard project](https://github.com/kulpreetchilana/Custom-iOS-Keyboards)
- You could assign a custom `inputView` to be displayed at the top of the system keyboard

Comment: Aaron Brager, Thank you! I try create keyboard with added my long-strings inside keyboard (email, logins, etc.). And this keyboard must be available from any application in iOS (not my application, any!)... I need solution for 'system' keyboard.